# Opening and closing connections from multiple functions with Peewee ORM

Tags: python, peewee

Currently i'm working on a program using the Peewee ORM (v2.10.2).
I've read in the docs that is good practice to explicitly open and close the connections in each function. However, as i've split up my code in different functions the situation occurs where function A uses function B and both independently open and close the DB connection. 
By doing so i get an exception that the connection is already closed, but also has the potential to disrupt the program if function B finishes and closes the connection and function A still has work to do on the database.

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate my problem:

```
def func_b():
    database.get_conn()
    #do database stuff
    database.close()

def func_a():
    database.get_conn()
    #do database stuff
    func_b()
    #do more database stuff <---this will fail cause the connection is already closed by func_b
    database.close() <---this wil raise an exception stating the connection is already closed
```

What would be the best way to avoid these problems?

Comment: The connection might be already closed due to time out or other reason. just check if it open then only close the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer seems obvious to me...if func_b is only called from func_a, then just remove the connection management code from func_b. The outermost function, func_a in this case, would handle it.

In a more general sense, typically there is a discrete unit of computation being done. In a web app, this would be a request/response -- thus, for web apps you typically open a connection when you receive a request, then close it upon sending the response.

For a script, you can just connect once at the start of the script and close the connection (implicitly or explicitly) when the script finishes.

Generally it is unwise to put your connection management code within functions that do things. Put them in the outermost scope -- the part that calls the functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In my case i use it to connect an pyside2 desktop app with Peewee to connect to the DB. Where function_b in my case would be used to repopulate a QtModel with new data from the DB and it is called from other functions but also directly on it's own. The problem i was hoping to solve by forcing the connect/close cycle in every function was that when a user leaves the app open for a longer period it won't crash on a DB connection timeout. Is there anyway to do this properly? Or is the only way for me catch the exceptions?

Comment: I think only MySQL will kill your connection after a timeout...if it's sqlite you don't need to worry. If it were me and I was concerned about a timeout, I'd implement a simple retry-once if it died/timed-out for some reason rather than trying to open/close it all over the place. That's expensive!

Comment: Working with MySQL, it happens fairly often that the users have to restart the app after a inactive period. A "retry once" is a good suggestion, i will definitely try that. I guess another option would be to create a decorator that opens a connection only if database.is_closed() == True, and explicitly close the connection in the class destructor. Thank you!